# Copy folder recursive in R

Tags: r

Am I missing something in the functions?
I want to copy a folder with some files and another subfolder from one location to another. I tried to use `file.copy(from, to, recursive=TRUE)` but it complains with an error message:

> In file.copy("my_folder", "new_folder",  :
>     'recursive' will be ignored as 'to' is not a single existing directory

The result is a file called `new_folder` with no content.

Is there a way to copy the complete folder structure with R?

Comment: What are you passing to the method? And what is the expected outcome? Would it work if recursive=FALSE? (it seems that you are passing the list of files to the method anyway, so why do you need recursive)

Comment: I pass folder names. The folders have subfolders and files within these subfolders... I want to create the complete subfolder structure within a new directory... I know the function name suggests not really "copying folder" but since there was a recursive flag, I thought it might help and there are no folder or directory copy functions in R.

Comment: ok, well, obviously these parameters do not work together, that's not how this method is intended. Why not loop (better: use apply) over the vectors/lists?

Comment: This is what I recognised :-) I was wondering if there is something else I could use, otherwise I have to construct something by hand... Since I have to create the substructure as well, it isn't just `apply`.

Comment: Could you show an example? I try to recreate your problem but I don't know if I have the correct folder structure. So far I created: 
content/
content/test.txt
content/test1.txt
content/sub/
content/sub/sub_test.txt
This seems to be what you explain in your second sentence but then I don't get why you need to pass several directories :)

Comment: You have to correct structure, I want to copy `content` to `content2`. So basically creating a new folder with the same structure as in `content`. I just want to copy into a new directory recursive.

Comment: Ah, now the coin dropped... :-) `'recursive' will be ignored as 'to' is not a single existing directory`... When I create `content2` first and then use `file.copy('content','content2',recursive=TRUE)` it works as expected... I just thought I can just use the `file.copy` function to create the directory as well.

Comment: Finally! :) That's what I was confused about ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, I just figured out what the error means... read every word carefully!

I have to create the new directory in advance and now I can copy everything...

```r
dir.create('new_folder')
file.copy("my_folder", "new_folder", recursive=TRUE)
```

This works as expected.

Comment: But it seems like you get `new_folder/new_folder/files` with this?

Comment: @Matifou check my answer if you want to avoid this

Answer (score 20):

I think `R.utils::copyDirectory(oldDir, newDir)` is the solution to what you're asking. It doesn't require creating `newDir` first, either.

Answer (score 15):

as @matifou says in the comments, the accepted answer by the questioneer himself is a bit confusing, because you end up with the copied folder inside a folder with the same name as the copied folder... to avoid this, do this instead:

case: you want to move folder_X to folder_Z.

```
# create empty folder Z inside folder X
dir.create('(...)/folder_X/folder_Z')
# copy the folder
file.copy('(...)/path_to_folder_Z', '(...)/folder_X')
```

so the second argument to file.copy shold be **just** folder_X, **and not** the newly created folder_Z inside folder_X.

Because if you do that, the folder structure will be like this, which is probably not what you want:

> (...)/folder_X/folder_Z/folder_Z

(Maybe this will save somebody the 10 minutes or so it took me to figure out)

Comment: I don't think this works if folder_X and folder_Z have the same parent directory. (i.e. what if user wants to copy <my_path>/folder_X to <my_path>/folder_X_copy?)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to copy files that lie inside one folder so that they lie inside of a second folder e.g.

```
dir1/file1.txt
dir1/nested/file2.txt
```

to:

```
dir2/file1.txt
dir2/nested/file2.txt
```

Then this code works:

```r
from <- "dir1"
to   <- "dir2"
file.copy(list.files(from, full.names = TRUE), 
          to, 
          recursive = TRUE)
```

Avoid using `recursive=TRUE` in the `list.files()` command otherwise you lose the nesting.

```r
file.copy(list.files(from, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE), 
          to, 
          recursive = TRUE)

# incorrect
# dir2/file1.txt
# dir2/file2.txt
```

Other answers above didn't help with above scenario, eg:

```r
file.copy(from, to, recursive=TRUE)

# incorrect - makes:
# dir2/dir1/file1.txt
# dir2/dir1/nested/file2.txt

file.copy('(...)/path_to_folder_Z', '(...)/folder_X')
# overwrites existing folder if in same parent directory
```

Comment: That's the best answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather write an R function that copies the directory using the Terminal. Here's what I use, but note that I wrote it only for Linux and OSX thus far.

```
dir.copy <- function(from, to) {
  os <- Sys.info()['sysname']
  if (os == "Darwin" || os == "Linux") {
    command <- sprintf("cp -R '%s' '%s'", from, to)
    system(command, intern = TRUE)   
  }
}
```

Quick, easy, and works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, I did this in the past as well if I need to speed up...
But I would do some sanitising first. Check if location exists, no `;`, other things maybe...
I guess you wouldn't like the user to name a folder like `from <- ". /dev/null ; rm -rf /"`...

Answer (score -1):

Here is another possibility :

```
create_Directory <- function(source_Directory = "C:/dir1",
                             target_Directory = "C:/dir2")
{
  setwd(source_Directory)
  list_Dirs <- list.dirs()
  setwd(target_Directory)
  bool_Dir_Exists <- dir.exists(list_Dirs)
  dirs_To_Create <- list_Dirs[!bool_Dir_Exists]
  for(dir in dirs_To_Create)
  {
    dir.create(dir)
  }
}

copy_Content_From_One_Directory_To_Another <- function(source_Directory = "C:/dir1",
                                                       target_Directory = "C:/dir2")
{
  #### Create the sub directories ####
  create_Directory(source_Directory = source_Directory,
                   target_Directory = target_Directory)

  #### Copy the files ####
  setwd(source_Directory)
  list_Files <- list.files(recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
  list_Files <- gsub(pattern = paste0("(\\.)",.Platform$file.sep), replacement = "", list_Files)

  file.copy(from = paste0(source_Directory,  .Platform$file.sep 
, list_Files),
            to = paste0(target_Directory, .Platform$file.sep , list_Files))
}

copy_Content_From_One_Directory_To_Another()
```

Comment: This code is not cross-platform compatible because it depends on forward slashes as path separators. Try to use .Platform$file.sep instead.

Comment: I modified the code to include .Platform$file.sep. Does it answer your concern?