# How to copy a folder in R

Tags: file, directory, copy

I'd like to know how to copy a folder that includes many levels of sub-folders from one drive to another drive. I want to keep the fold structure the same. I want to copy all files except that file size is larger than 10 MB.
Please give me a hint. Thank you!

Comment: This was answered in another thread already:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475475/4783417

Comment: I didn't see how to screen out files according to size in that thread.